# Need to update multiple SharePoint calendars

Tags: calendar, outlook

Since I'm headed out of office next week, I'd like to update all of my SharePoint projects' calendars.  Right now, I have to enter my OOO time in my Outlook, then go to each SharePoint project site and update those calendars individually.

Is there a way to update all of the SharePoint calendars with my OOO time at once?  I don't want to share my whole Outlook calendar with each of the SharePoint calendars...just specific events/appointments.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box there is no solution available.

You have to right a small console app to update a specific day event in all the calendars of your site